# Caterpillar decomposition of trees

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, tree

Can any tree on $n$ nodes be decomposed into a set of $O(\log n)$ [caterpillars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caterpillar_tree)? If not, what is the maximum number of caterpillars required? Are there efficient algorithms for finding the decomposition?

Any papers on this topic will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

It seems this is false in general. Take the tree with a central node $x$, connected to a bunch of nodes $y_1,\dots,y_n$. Each node $y_i$ is additionally connected to a node $z_i$.

The total number of nodes is $N=2n+1$.

Any caterpillar in this tree can contain at most two $z$ nodes, and therefore, $n/2$ caterpillars are needed to cover it. So it is impossible to cover it with $O(log N)$ caterpillars.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to add to dkuper's answer that it is possible to split every tree into a *hierarchy* of caterpillars, whose depth is at most $O(\log n)$. This can be done with Tarjan's [heavy-light edge decompostion](http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Heavy-light_decomposition). Just take the maximal heavy-edge paths as the spines of the caterpillars.